# Multiple domain cookies been displayed under a given webpage

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

If sharing cookies across multiple domains is not allowed, How come I can see cookies from multiple websites under a given webpage?

[image]

Comment: Because that is the browser doing that not the webpage

Answer (score 1):

Oh... I just saw that Facebook, Google and other place an iframe into your webpage to be used to communicate with their domains. Therefore these cookies are from other websites within my webpage because these iframe were placed in it... sneaky...

Facebook calls it "Cross Domain Communication Frame"

[image]